# How to fetch a Restaurant by its menuId?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have set up Core data in my application, with two entities: Restaurant and Menu. There are about 30 or so restaurants, and 6 menus. One menu can belong to several restaurants.

However, each Restaurant entity has a menuId field. Is there a way to retrieve the specific menu entity according to which menuId the Restaurant entity has?

I also have a problem with values being stored more than once, even though they are the same. How can I prevent that from happening?

I'm pretty new to Core data, so any best-practice tips would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that Core Data is not a database. It's an object graph that can be persisted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `NSFetchRequest` to retrieve menus by their id, but it would actually be better to define a *relationship* from your Restaurant entity to your Menu entity (and vice-versa). Internally, that does pretty much the same thing as your menu id attribute, but it's much more convenient to use.

Answer (score 0):

You're following a database approach, based on tables and IDs to link these tables. This is wrong in Core Data, you must follow a object graph approach and CoreData will transform it to a corresponding SQlite database in a manner completely transparent to you.

So given the entities °Restaurant" and "Menu" you will create:
- in the entity "Restaurant" a 1-to-many relationship to "Menu" called "menus"
- in the entity "Menu" a 1-to-many relationship to "Restaurant" called "restaurants"

You will just need to add each restaurant menu to the NSSet corresponding to the menus relationship for a given menu, and vice versa. As you can see in this way you don't need to care about IDs, but just the object relationships.

As far as repeated data, this depends on you. Normally you should have a way to identify the unicity of an object (e.g.: the menu name, the restaurant name) and then try to retrieve it from Core Data before adding it as a new object.